# R: How do I simulate a time series data in replicate until some conditions are met

Tags: r, replication, arima

I want to simulate a time series data that follows AR(1) with phi=0.6 such that if I tried my first simulation I will check if it follows the AR(1). If not, I will make the second trial, together with the first I will get the average of the two trials to form the series. I test the order until it conforms to the AR(1) otherwise I keep adding one (1) to my trials until I confirmed that the average of the trials is a time series of AR(1) model.

After that, I will check if the coefficient of the AR(1) is equal to phi=0.6. if not I will add yet one(1) to my trials until I check that the phi=0.6.

**MWE*

```
library(FitAR)
n=50
a=0.6
count=0
e <- rnorm(n+100)
x <- double(n+100)
x[1] <- rnorm(1)
for(i in 2:(n+100)) {
  x[i] <- a * x[i-1] + e[i]
  }
x <- ts(x[-(1:100)])
p=SelectModel(x, lag.max = 14, Criterion = "BIC", Best=1)
if(p >= 2){
  count <- count + 1
  mat <- replicate(count, x)
  x <- as.ts(rowMeans(mat))
}
fit=arima(x,order = c(p,0,0))
my_coef=fit$coef
if(my_coef != 0.6){
  mat <- replicate(count + 1, x)
  x <- as.ts(rowMeans(mat))
}
my_coefficients=my_coef[!names(my_coef) == 'intercept']
print(my_coefficients)
print(paste0("AR(2) model count is: ", count_coef))
```

Comment: Daniel, please go through your old posts and close the questions for which you have received help by setting the green check mark next to the answer. That way you help keeping SO tidy, and make it easier for others to identify relevant questions; it is also the recommended way to say "thank you" around here.

Comment: I had already advised in a previous answer that you should use `arima.sim` to simulate data from a specific AR(I)MA process. Is there a particular reason for not using `arima.sim`?

Comment: The reason is that the first observation can not be set, but with my own way I tell R to use the first or the first two random numbers to start the series instead of making the first sample zero.

Comment: can undo the downvote as I have done the needful?

Comment: `arima.sim()` have so many hidden issues that I can not argue which only the authors can defend, my style of time series simulation is open and I can argue it mathematically.

Comment: Thanks for tidying up some of your posts; there are more posts that you should close though! I'm not sure what "hidden issues" you're referring to with `arima.sim`. The function does exactly as told, and should be used for simulating data from AR(I)MA processes. No need to re-invent the wheel and write your own poorly implemented simulation routine. Anyway, it's your call. However, it's difficult to help as your code is messy and you refuse to take on advice given to you in various earlier answers. Perhaps somebody else is more savvy/keen to work through your code.

Comment: Can show me how one can  use `arima.sim()` function to simulate 50 time series data wit `mean=0` and `sd=2`?

Comment: Done. Please see my post below.

Answer (score 2):

We can generate time series data for 100 time points of a white noise ARIMA(0, 0, 0) process with zero mean and standard deviation `sd = 2` in the following way

```r
set.seed(2020)
ts <- arima.sim(model = list(), n = 100, sd = 2)
```

This is explained in the documentation `?arima.sim`

Usage:

> ```
> arima.sim(model, n, rand.gen = rnorm, innov = rand.gen(n, ...),
>            n.start = NA, start.innov = rand.gen(n.start, ...),
>            ...)
>
>  ...: additional arguments for ‘rand.gen’.  Most usefully, the
>       standard deviation of the innovations generated by ‘rnorm’
>       can be specified by ‘sd’.
> ```

---

To generate 50 time series, we can use `replicate`

```r
set.seed(2020)
mat <- replicate(50, arima.sim(model = list(), n = 100, sd = 2))
```

The resulting object is a `matrix` with dimensions `100 x 50`.

---

We can confirm that the standard deviation is indeed `sd = 2`

```r
summary(apply(mat, 2, sd))
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.
#1.669   1.899   2.004   2.006   2.107   2.348
```

```r
library(tidyverse)
apply(mat, 2, sd) %>%
    enframe() %>%
    ggplot(aes(value)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 10)
```

[image]